# How to change the background of a row in an HTML table using toggle classlist

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background color of a row if the value in the table cell goes above a certain value.

I have tried implementing the toggle class as well as adding and removing classes with no luck. When I manually implemented the background color it worked.

I know I am trying to toggle a class vs a style, but is there any way I can toggle a style to change the background color?

```js
var mq2 = 5;
if (mq2 >= 5) {
  document.getElementById("row1").classlist.toggle("change2");
} else {
  document.getElementById("row1").classlist.toggle("change1");
}
```

```css
.change1 {
  background-color: #FF6347;
}

.change2 {
  background-color: #90EE90;
}
```

```html
<tr id="row1">
```

Comment: are you converting the string(text of `<td>`) to Number>

Comment: <td id = "mq2"></td> This is outputting the value assigned to the variable mq2 in the table cell. The value is coming from Firestore database.

Comment: Why don't you try toggling the class itself, like `toggleClass`?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to assist you.

Comment: Maybe the row just doesn't have dimensions that's why the changes can't be seen

Comment: I went a different route and created a function to update the background color. Within my firestore listener I called the function if the document field was modified above the threshold

Comment: I used variable.style.backgroundColor = "color code" in my function

Comment: Note that the `tr` is not styled directly, it is the cells within the row that recieve the styling. See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#Basic_styling

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. You could improve it by creating a variable referencing the element

```
const row = document.getElementById("row1"); 
if(someCondition) {
   row.classList.toggle("change2");
} else {
   row.classList.toggle("change1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking is fine, just make sure you capitalize `classList` correctly.

```
document.getElementById('row1').classList.toggle('change1');
```